# Add relationship to many to many in entity framework code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

I want to add a relationship between multiple existing entities and another existing entity. Here is my model:

```
public class Term
{
    public int TermId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubForm> SubForms { get; set; }
}

public class SubForm
{
    public int SubFormId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Term> Terms { get; set; }
}
```

I have an update repository method as follows:

```
public IQueryable<Term> GetTerms()
{
    IQueryable<Term> query = db.Terms.AsNoTracking();
    return query;
}

public Term UpdateTerm(Term term, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<Term, object>>> properties)
{
    if (term.TermId == 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Term does not exist");
    }
    db.Terms.Attach(term);
    if (properties != null)
    {
        foreach (var selector in properties)
        {
            string propertyName = Helpers.PropertyToString(selector.Body);
            db.Entry(term).Property(propertyName).IsModified = true;
        }
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return term;
}
```

Now I assume this would work when I make this call in my service layer:

```
public void AddFormToTerm(int termId, int formId)
{
    var term = termsRepository.GetTerms().FirstOrDefault(t => t.TermId == termId);
    var subForms = termsRepository.GetSubForms().Where(t => t.FormId == formId);

    //I assume this would work by adding existing forms to an existing term.
    foreach (var subForm in subForms)
    {
        term.SubForms.Add(subForm);
    }

    termsRepository.UpdateTerm(term, null);
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't get updated, there is nothing in the intermediate table when I checked the database. No exception was also thrown.

Comment: I've run through a simple setup of the above without the properties bit and I get a records in the link table. Have you tried without the properties bit with your setup?

Comment: @WestDiscGolf I added code to skip the property stuff if it is null. It still didn't create it for me. Did you use db.Terms.Attach?

Comment: I use no tracking to get the entities.

Comment: Yup I used the db.Terms.Attach. By the looks of it it may have been a NoTracking issue. Looks like you've got it sorted though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `AsNoTracking` in this case is the problem. Without `AsNoTracking` it will work. You must keep in mind that you can update a many-to-many relationship only with the change tracking mechanism. But in your code the EF context will know about `term` and the `SubForms` collection for the first time when you call `Attach` in your `UpdateTerm` method. EF does not notice that you did add the `SubForms` to the `term` because those entities were not attached to the context (since you used `AsNoTracking` = "EF, please do not attach to the context!"). But after `Attach` nothing happened anymore before you called `SaveChanges` = No change = No database commands.
So removing `AsNoTracking` (or creating another method or a parameter to load *with* tracking) is the best option. Everything else will involve ugly "tricks" like this:

```
public Term UpdateTerm(Term term, ...)
{
    //...

    // Restore the state before adding the subforms = current state in DB
    var tempSubForms = term.SubForms;
    term.SubForms = null;

    // Inform EF about this state = term exists, subforms exist
    // in DB but no relationships
    db.Terms.Attach(term);
    foreach (var subForm in tempSubForms)
        db.SubForms.Attach(subForm);

    // Change the state: EF change tracking recognizes this
    term.SubForms = tempSubForms;

    //...

    // EF now will send INSERT statements for the join table
    db.SaveChanges();
    return term;
}
```

Comment: I just removed notracking on all my get statements. Would this affect any code that someone else could have written?

Comment: @Lolcoder: Of course, it will affect other code (performance, bugs if the loaded entities get attached to other contexts, whatever...). I wouldn't do this carelessly. Better create new methods or parameter with default value corresponding to the old behaviour if you are not sure about the impact of this change.

Comment: can the same repository be used to remove relationships or I'll have to write a new method for this?

Comment: @Lolcoder: You must load the original term with all subForms (using `Include` for example) from the database and then remove the items you want to remove (change tracking will recognize this as relationship change). After that you can use your UpdateTerm method.